# SqlBulkCopy many-to-many table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

I am wondering if there is any possibility to get last inserted ID in SqlBulkCopy?

```
Table 1     Table2   Many-To-Many-Table
attribute  attribute Table1.id, Table2.id
```

I have middle table for many to Manyrelationship So I need to get last insertd Id from table1 and table2, and then I need to insert both of them in Many-To-Many-Table.

Is that possible?

Comment: hope you do not need to create third table for many-to-one relationship

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I had many-to-many-table in mind.